# How to display and save current date and Time in UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm new in ios.I want to display and save current date and time in UITableViewCell.

Comment: Why u won't search properly before writing the question??? It's already been explained on stackoverflow number of times

Comment: "I want to" - You **want** to? And you **want** us to do your work without you having done any research? Now that's not going to work, definitively.

Comment: `[NSDate date]` will give you the current date. Create any holder (label, text) to diaplay. for showing use userdefaults or plist.

Comment: No response For anyone ? where are you ?

Comment: Before you ask any question atleast take the risk to Google it!

Comment: Manikandan - welcome to stack.  The reaction you're getting is SO isn't really a code it for me kind of site.  A good question shows what you've tried (research, your code) with a specific problem.  The faq is a good place to start: http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Comment: `UITableViewCell` is not for `new in ios`. You have learnt all the basics of ios/obj-c only then you reached here, isn't it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add a `UILabel` to your cell and then use the following piece of code:

```
NSDate *currDate = [NSDate date];
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd.MM.YY HH:mm:ss"];
NSString *dateString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:currDate];

yourLabel.text=dateString
```

Comment: +1 for helping someone with such a one-liner question!